# css transforms overflow:hidden cause blurry content in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to apply a SkewY css3d transform mask on content inside of a div. For that, I am using an outer div that gets a skewY of -3deg and I have a other div inside having a skew in the opposite direction (3deg).

Giving overflow:hidden to the outer div to create the mask effect is causing the content inside of the inner div, especially images, to lose their initial quality. Would be great to not having that content blurred on Chrome and keeping the mask through the overflow.

Here is the code that I use for so far:

CSS:

```
.outer {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 51%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner{
    -webkit-transform: skewY(3deg) translateY(-50%);
    transform: skewY(3deg) translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #595b5e;
    height: calc(100% + 130px);
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><img src="highqualityimage.jpg" alt="" class=""><img src="" alt=""></img></div>
</div>
```

and an example link of what it is doing (try to remove overflow hidden to see the difference) : http://codepen.io/guilanier/pen/bNMvmO

Comment: Do you have live demo for it?

Comment: yep, just right there : [codepen link](http://codepen.io/guilanier/pen/bNMvmO) we can see that the image is in a better quality by removing the overflow on outer

Comment: Image is not displaying at all

Comment: It is `backface-visibility` and not `overflow: hidden;` that is causing that blur. Even if you use `transform: rotateZ(0deg);`, the blur will still be visible.  
If you remove that, you'll get jagged edges.

Comment: right ! that's solve the thing, thanks !